# Files marked as 'Deleted' are reported as 'Missing' in LibGit2Sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp, git-status

When viewing my repository status with Git Bash I can see many files that are marked as 'Deleted'. LibGit2Sharp RepositoryStatus reports these files as "Missing". The RepositoryStatus object also has a collection "Removed".

What is the difference between these two? Should deleted files not be marked as "Removed"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what is the difference between these two?

**Missing** and **Removed** are entries of the **[FileStatus](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/8c32b6160a49890e26100148e73c1558b0daa9af/LibGit2Sharp/FileStatus.cs#L9)** enumeration.

As stated by the xml documentation

- *Missing* means *"The file has been deleted from the working directory. A previous version exists in the Index."*
- *Removed* means *"The deletion of a file has been promoted from the working directory to the Index. A previous version exists in the Head."*

They can be seen as specific states of a file lifecycle. Let's consider a file which exists in the working directory, in the index and in the Head. Its status is **Unaltered**.

When being suppressed from the working directory (ie. deleted from the filesystem), the status of the file turns into ***Missing***

If now, one stages the suppression of the file, it disappears from the Index and the status becomes **Removed**

> Should deleted files not be marked as, "Removed"?

Git uses the same word **deleted** to describe the two states. However, there are some visual clues to let you disambiguate them.

When running `git status`

- **Missing** files are being listed under the `Changes not staged for commit:` section and the deleted word is colored in **red**
- **Removed** files are being listed under the `Changes to be committed:` section and the deleted word is colored in **green**

Comment: Thanks for the through answer!